# Timezone in email Invoice is different than than store

Tags: magento-1.7, timezone

Timezone set in the backend - http://prntscr.com/44ti3x

But timezone showing in email invoice - http://prntscr.com/44tin0

How can I change this to IST ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in the e-mail template is hard coded.
Just edit the file: `app/locale/{lang_ISO}/template/email/sales/invoice_new.html`  and fill in your correct hours and timezone.

You may want to look in the other e-mail templates also. There are a lot of them with this hardcoded text.